# Is there a way to "consolidate" a child table in a 1-to-many table relation?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to "consolidate" a child table in a one-to-many table relation? My schema consists of three tables that have nested one-to-many relationships:

```
Reports --< Domains --< Findings
```

I am having to populate these tables by reading thousands (~30,000) of excel files. It is only as I look at the `Findings` table that I see there are many identical, duplicated strings in there (I've since found out these multi-sheet excel reports are generated programmatically).

Is there an efficient way I can check if a string that would go in the `Findings` table already exists? ... **and only add it if it does not already exist?**

Below is a snippet of my code where I am adding the ORM instances just for reference/context:

```
    _report = Report(**report)
    for r in range(_reportdf.shape[0]):
        _domain = Domain(**domains[r])
        _report.domains.append(_domain)
        for f in findings[r]:
            _finding = Finding(finding= f[0], value= f[1])
            _domain.variables.append(_finding)
            session.add(_finding)

        session.add(_report)                
        session.add(_domain)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: For bulk operations involving tens of thousands of rows I wouldn't recommend creating ORM objects and managing them in a Session. Instead, I'd suggest that you use SQLAlchemy Core to assemble your rows in temporary tables and then bulk insert (or upsert) into the main tables.

Comment: Thank you - it's something I was wondering (although hadn't considered temporary tables!)....however, the next project is to provide these tables via REST API. I was under the impression that SQLAlchemy ORM with Flask would be the right choice?

Comment: That could very well be, but it is important to remember that just because one part of a SQLAlchemy project uses ORM does not mean that the whole project must *only* use ORM. And, with version 1.4 (currently in Beta) a lot of work has gone into reconciling past differences between SQLA ORM and SQLA Core to make it even easier to use whichever approach is best suited to a particular task.

Comment: Great news - I did not know the could be used interchangeably! Thanks again @GordThompson